# ExtJs Multiple Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4.1

I am trying to learn extjs 4.1 MVC. I have a controler with multiple ajax calls. When the code runs on Firefox I can see all the ajax calls are made but the alert of only one of the sucess method is coming up. While the data is available in view for all 4 calls. Any sugestions what I am doing wrong ?
Code below:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.StartupController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

models : [ 'BasicModel' ],

stores : [ 'UserStore','RoleStore','RegionStore','ProductStore','FunctionStore' ],

views : [ 'FooterContainer', 'BodyContainer' ],

init : function() {
    this.loadStore();
    this.loadRole();
    this.loadRegion();
    this.loadFunction();
    this.loadProduct();
    this.control({

    });
},
loadRole: function(){
    // create an AJAX request for role
    var roleStore = this.getRoleStoreStore();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'forms/loadRole',
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        params : {
            "test" : "testParam"
        },
        success : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            roleStore.loadData(jsonResp);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Info", "UserName from Server 1: "+ jsonResp.userName);
        },
        failure : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.decode(response);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Error", jsonResp.error);
        }
    });
},
loadRegion: function(){
    // create an AJAX request for region
    var regionStore = this.getRegionStoreStore();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'forms/loadRegion',
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        params : {
            "test" : "testParam"
        },
        success : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            regionStore.loadData(jsonResp);

            Ext.Msg.alert("Info", "UserName from Server 2: "+ jsonResp.userName);
        },
        failure : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.decode(response);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Error", jsonResp.error);
        }
    });
},
loadFunction: function(){
    // create an AJAX request for function
    var functionStore = this.getFunctionStoreStore();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'forms/loadFunction',
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        params : {
            "test" : "testParam"
        },
        success : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            functionStore.loadData(jsonResp);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Info", "UserName from Server 3: "+ jsonResp.userName);
        },
        failure : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.decode(response);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Error", jsonResp.error);
        }
    });
},
loadProduct: function(){
    // create an AJAX request for product
    var productStore = this.getProductStoreStore();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'forms/loadProduct',
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        params : {
            "test" : "testParam"
        },
        success : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            productStore.loadData(jsonResp);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Info", "UserName from Server 4: "+ response.responseText);
        },
        failure : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.decode(response);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Error", jsonResp.error);
        }
    });
},
loadStore : function() {
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess what's happening is ext only has a single instance of the MessageBox component and it is getting called four times...But you can only see the last one.  If you just want some form of feedback I'd go with using console.log instead of Ext.Msg.alert.

Comment: You are correct. While I was testing I carefully observed. The MessageBox remeaied there and the message changed. Since my messages where similar with only change in number it seemed that only one is coming up. Changed the code to "console.log" as it was just for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

just do it like this, put the next ajax request on success response

```
    Ext.define('App.controller.StartupController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

models : [ 'BasicModel' ],

stores : [ 'UserStore','RoleStore','RegionStore','ProductStore','FunctionStore' ],

views : [ 'FooterContainer', 'BodyContainer' ],

init : function() {
    this.loadStore();
    this.loadRole();
    this.control({

    });
},
loadRole: function(){
    // create an AJAX request for role
    var roleStore = this.getRoleStoreStore();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'forms/loadRole',
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        params : {
            "test" : "testParam"
        },
        success : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            roleStore.loadData(jsonResp);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Info", "UserName from Server 1: "+ jsonResp.userName);
            this.loadRegion();
        },
        failure : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.decode(response);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Error", jsonResp.error);
        }
    });
},
loadRegion: function(){
    // create an AJAX request for region
    var regionStore = this.getRegionStoreStore();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'forms/loadRegion',
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        params : {
            "test" : "testParam"
        },
        success : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            regionStore.loadData(jsonResp);

            Ext.Msg.alert("Info", "UserName from Server 2: "+ jsonResp.userName);
            this.loadFunction();
        },
        failure : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.decode(response);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Error", jsonResp.error);
        }
    });
},
loadFunction: function(){
    // create an AJAX request for function
    var functionStore = this.getFunctionStoreStore();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'forms/loadFunction',
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        params : {
            "test" : "testParam"
        },
        success : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            functionStore.loadData(jsonResp);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Info", "UserName from Server 3: "+ jsonResp.userName);
            this.loadProduct();
        },
        failure : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.decode(response);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Error", jsonResp.error);
        }
    });
},
loadProduct: function(){
    // create an AJAX request for product
    var productStore = this.getProductStoreStore();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'forms/loadProduct',
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        params : {
            "test" : "testParam"
        },
        success : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            productStore.loadData(jsonResp);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Info", "UserName from Server 4: "+ response.responseText);
        },
        failure : function(response) {
            var jsonResp = Ext.decode(response);
            Ext.Msg.alert("Error", jsonResp.error);
        }
    });
},
loadStore : function() {
}
```

Comment: This did not work and issue was same. As suggested below by "Gordon Bockus" the instance of MessageBox is same. Moreover I will loose the "Async" calls with this approach.